# Truncate a string without cut in the middle of a word in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, truncate

How can i truncate a text to the closest position with rails 3 whithout cut in the middle of a word?

For exemple, I have the string :

```
"Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum."
```

If i cut it, i want to cut like this :

```
"Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl ..."
```

And not :

```
"Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl conse..."
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you pass in a separator to the truncate method it will perform a natural word break instead of truncating at a middle of a word

Something like this should work (vary the length to whatever you want to remove it altogether if you want the default of 30 characters):

```
truncate("Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.", :length => 17, :separator => ' ')
```

More information about the options you can have in truncate can be found in the [Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate)

Answer (score 9):

Starting `Rails 4.2` there is a new `ActiveSupport` method called [`string#truncate_words`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/truncate_words). It truncates a string by number of words which makes it impossible to have a cut in the middle of a word.

```
'And they found that many people were sleeping better.'.truncate_words(5, omission: '... (continued)')
```

which returns

```
"And they found that many... (continued)"
```

Answer (score 8):

Truncate is a great option, but if you want to have **complete word detection**, regex is your solution.  I would recommend something like this:

```
string.match(/^.{0,30}\b/)[0]
```

Or you can put this in a function

```
def shorten(string, count)
  string.match(/^.{0,#{count}}\b/)[0]
end
```

#### Update

According to [Rails documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/String/truncate), you can pass regex into the truncate method, like so:

```
'Once upon a time in a world far far away'.truncate(27, separator: /\s/)
```

Both of these options offer far better word boundary detection than passing in a space character into the truncate method.