# Rails truncate string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `str='My long string with this text'`

I know about `truncate str, length: 20, omission: ''`,but it cuts words

My goal is to keep full word after truncation. Is it possible?

string can be random length

Comment: You can use separator option.
Please visit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714045/truncate-a-string-without-cut-in-the-middle-of-a-word-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation:

```
truncate("Once upon a time in a world far far away", length: 17)
# => "Once upon a ti"

truncate("Once upon a time in a world far far away", length: 17, separator: ' ')
# => "Once upon a"
```

Please find more on this in the following SO link:

[Truncate a string without cut in the middle of a word in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714045/truncate-a-string-without-cut-in-the-middle-of-a-word-in-rails)